# Does Qrypt's BLAST protocol based on "Doubly-Affine Extractors" use public-key or symmetric-key cryptography?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, key-exchange, protocol-analysis

The company Qrypt [states](https://docs.qrypt.com/concepts/key-generation-architecture/) that "Key distribution based on asymmetric algorithms is a weak link for cryptography" and claims to "enable encryption without distributing encryption keys" using its BLAST architecture. It gives non-technical explanations [here](https://docs.qrypt.com/concepts/key-generation-architecture/) and [here](https://www.qrypt.com/resources/going-beyond-the-limitations-of-quantum-key-distribution-qkd-with-qrypt/) and a technical explanation of the underlying math [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Edodis/ps/blast.pdf). But I can't find a simple, clear, high-level explanation in terms of standard cryptographic concepts.

Qrypt lists the following steps in BLAST protocol:

> 1. Client A determines the key generation requirements: BLAST servers to be used, the sampling seeds, and extraction parameters​.
> 2. Clients share the key generation requirements – seeds, extraction parameters​.
> 3. Each client independently samples BLAST APIs, assembling identical blocks of random [*sic*] on each client.​
> 4. Clients locally extracts keys - resulting in identical encryption keys which were never distributed​.

From this description, it sounds like this protocol is similar to some kind of [key encapsulation mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation_mechanism): it uses some kind of cryptographic mechanism to securely exchange an encrypted *seed* message (the "key generation requirements" in step 2), and then each client uses something like a key derivation function to convert that seed message into a symmetric key. So it technically true that "no encryption keys are transmitted", but are there seed messages transmitted which, if intercepted, would allow an attacker to calculate the keys?

If this general picture is correct, are the "key generation requirements" transmitted using public-key or symmetric-key encryption?

(Qrpyt also uses quantum instead of classical random generators, but let's set that part aside and simply assume that they have reliable RNGs and focus on the key exchange agreement step.)